# File download percent finishes at 74%

Tags: java, android

I am downloading a file from a server and am having a minor issue where, when the download is complete, the percentage of the file always stops at 74%, but the download is 100% complete.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);

int fileSize = mConnection.getContentLength();

InputStream input = mConnection.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // I think its this line that would be causing the issue
int count;
int total = 0;
while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    if (fileSize > 0)
        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileSize));
    output.write(buffer, 0, count);
    if (isCancelled()) 
        break;
}
```

I think its the line where `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]` is causing the issue as it may not be calculating the file size correctly or something along those lines?

I would like it to finish at 100% instead of 74%

Comment: The last publish isn't getting noted, Just publishProgress on `onPostExecute`

Comment: Can you check if `connection.getContentLength()` is actually returning the size of file?

Comment: @AmitKumar yes it is, the progress works fine while downloading the file, but stops AKA finishes at 74%

Comment: @SamzSakerz so you say call publishProgress(100) in `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Yes, Try it. and see if it works

Comment: @SamzSakerz im sure that will work, but then its not calculating the correct file size somewhere? Shouldnt it simply calculate the percentage left until the file is fully downloaded?

Comment: @x10sion check answer

Comment: From HttpURLConnection documentation:

URLConnection.getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted and cannot be used to predict how many bytes can be read from URLConnection.getInputStream() for compressed streams. Is your stream compressed? This way there will be no match between the bytes count read from your input stream and the real number of bytes of the connection stream

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi great explanation, did not know that. Have you got a solution

Comment: @x10sion Gzip compression is enabled by default, you can disable it by calling  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity"); to understand if compression is the reason of the wrong calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file download ends after `74%` the file doesn't publish the changes because the background method does not get called again after file download finishes.
you can publish the changes on your `onPostExecute` Method

```
void onPostExecute(String result){
   publishProgress(100);
}
```

Comment: this does not work, as it still stops at 74% then continues because the file has completed the download

Comment: What do you mean `then continues`?

Comment: Can you share URL of the file you are trying to download?

Comment: im downloading an apk, the running the apk when its completed, so the progress dialog stops at 74%, the starts the installation process

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Okay how about call `publishProgress(100) ` at the end of the while loop?